# Посчитать сумму значений в Map через Stream Api

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Есть коллекция `ArrayList`, которая хранит в себе объекты класса `Student(<HashMap<Subject, Integer> rating, String name>)`.
Необходимо посчитать средний балл по конкретному предмету при помощи Stream API.
Пытался это делать так:

```java
sumOnSubjectInGroup = studentsInGroup.stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getRating().entrySet().iterator().next().getKey().equals(subject))
    .mapToInt(e -> e.getRating().entrySet().iterator().next().getValue())
    .reduce(0, (x, y) -> x + y);
countMarkInGroup = (int) studentsInGroup.stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getRating().entrySet().iterator().next().getKey().equals(subject))
    .count();
return (double) sumOnSubjectInGroup / countMarkInGroup;
```

Где:

- `sumOnSubjectInGroup` - суммарная оценка по определенному предмету (subject) всех студентов.
- `countMarkInGroup` - количество таких оценок.
- `studentsInGroup` - коллекция со всеми объектами Student.
- `getRating()` - возвращает `HashMap<Subject, Integer>` со списком предметов и оценок по нему.
- `subject` - предмет, по которому я хочу узнать средний бал.

```java
    Student student1 = new Student(new HashMap<>() {{
                    put(BIOLOGY, 8);
                    put(MATH, 4);
                    put(ENGLISH, 10);
                    put(PHYSIC, 6);
                }}, "Ivanov Ivan Ivanovich");
    Student student2 = new Student(new HashMap<>() {{
                    put(MATH, 5);
                    put(ASTRONOMY, 6);
                    put(CHEMISTRY, 2);
                }}, "Petrov Petr Petrovovich");
    
    Student student3 = new Student(new HashMap<>() {{
                    put(ASTRONOMY, 7);
                    put(PHYSIC, 4);
                    put(HISTORY, 5);
                }}, "Vasiliev Vasiliy Vasilievich");
    
    Student student4 = new Student(new HashMap<>() {{
                    put(ASTRONOMY, 4);
                    put(MATH, 10);
                }}, "Sergeev Sergei Sergeevich");      
    
    Group group1 = new Group("TEEO", new ArrayList<>() {{
                    add(student1);
                    add(student2);
                }});
    Group group2 = new Group("THEORETICAL PHYSICS", new ArrayList<>() {{
                    add(student3);
                    add(student4);
                }});
    
    Faculty faculty1 = new Faculty("PHYSICS FACULTY", new ArrayList<>() {{
                    add(group1);
                    add(group2);
                }});
    
    faculty1.averageMarkOnSubjectOnFaculty(MATH);

public void averageMarkOnSubjectOnFaculty(Subject subject) {
        averageMarkOnSomeSubjectOnFaculty = facultyList.stream()
                .map(e -> e.getStudentsInGroup())
                .map(e -> e.iterator().next())
                .filter(e -> e.getRating().containsKey(subject))
                .mapToInt(e -> e.getRating().get(subject))
                .average()
                .orElse(0.0);

        if (averageMarkOnSomeSubjectOnFaculty == 0)
            System.out.println("There are no students on the faculty " + getNameFaculty() +
                    " which learning " + subject + ".");
        else System.out.println("On the faculty " + getNameFaculty() + " in the subject " + subject +
                " average mark " + averageMarkOnSomeSubjectOnFaculty);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Допустим у Вас есть такой студент:

```
class Student{

    Map<String, Integer> rating;
    String name;

    public Student(String name){
        rating = new HashMap<>();
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Student rate(String subject, Integer rate){
        rating.put(subject, rate);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Тогда метод подсчета может быть таким:

```
private static Double avgRate(String subject, List<Student> students){
    return students
            .stream()
            .mapToInt(student -> student.rating.get(subject))
            .average()
            .orElse(0);
}
```

**UPD:** Если мы используем факультет и группы, можно делать так:

```
private static Double avgRate(String subject, Faculty faculty){
    return faculty
            .getGroups()
            .stream()
            .flatMap(group -> group.getStudents().stream())
            .mapToInt(student -> student.rating.get(subject))
            .average()
            .orElse(0);
}
```

Где из факультета мы извлекаем лист групп, затем используем `flatmap` для того чтобы раскрыть из каждой группы стрим со студентами. И далее как в первом примере.

Comment: Спасибо. Это помогло. Но при более сложной структуре (ArrayList - Arraylist - Student (<HashMap <Subject, Integer> rating, String name>) получаю неверный результат. https://prnt.sc/u7pck4

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос данные на которых Вы прогоняете свой тест. Попробуем решить.

Comment: @robert0801 посмотрел скриншот. Что-то с итератопом Вы там намудрили. Зачем Вы его используете в методе map?

Comment: это для меня самый очевидный способ перебрать Stream<ArrayList<Student>> и получить Stream<Student>, но, как  понял, неверный. На выходе я получаю некое значение, но оно некорректно.

Comment: Смотрите обновление

Answer (score 1):

При использовании конструкции `e.getRating().entrySet().iterator().next()` фактически Вы получите рандомный предмет, что приведет к некорректным данным.

```
package com.somepackage;

import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.ToString;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {

    @Getter
    @Builder
    @ToString
    @EqualsAndHashCode
    static class Subject {

        private String name;

    }

    @Getter
    @Builder
    @ToString
    @EqualsAndHashCode
    static class Student {

        private Map<Subject, Integer> rating;
        private String name;

    }

    private static List<Subject> prepareSubjects(String...names) {
        return Arrays.stream(names)
                .map(n -> Subject.builder()
                        .name(n)
                        .build())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private static List<Student> prepareStudents(List<Subject> subjects, String...names) {
        return Arrays.stream(names)
                .map(n -> Student.builder()
                        .name(n)
                        .rating(subjects.stream()
                                .collect(
                                        Collectors.toMap(
                                                s -> s,
                                                s -> ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 6))))
                        .build())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private static <T> T randomValue(
            final List<T> values) {
        return values.get(
                ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(
                        values.size()));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Subject> subjects =
                prepareSubjects(
                        "Java", "C#", "Kotlin", "Scala");
        List<Student> students =
                prepareStudents(
                        subjects,
                        "Ivanova", "Petrov", "Sidorov", "Fedorova");
        Map<Subject, Double> ratings =
                students.stream()
                        .flatMap(s -> s.getRating().entrySet().stream())
                        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                                e -> e.getKey(),
                                HashMap::new,
                                Collectors.averagingDouble(e -> e.getValue())));
        Subject randomSubject =
                randomValue(subjects);
        double randomSubjectRating1 =
                students.stream()
                        .mapToInt(s -> s.getRating().get(randomSubject))
                        .average()
                        .orElse(0.0);
        double randomSubjectRating2 =
                students.stream()
                        .flatMap(s -> s.getRating().entrySet().stream())
                        .filter(e -> randomSubject.equals(e.getKey()))
                        .collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(e -> e.getValue()));
        System.out.println("Students: " + students);
        System.out.println("Ratings: " + ratings);
        System.out.println("Rating by random subject #1: " + randomSubjectRating1);
        System.out.println("Rating by random subject #2: " + randomSubjectRating2);
    }

}
```